# Replace string between square brackets with sed

Tags: string, replace, sed, brackets

I have some strings in a textfile that look like this:

```
[img:3gso40ßf]
```

I want to replace them to look like normal BBCode:

```
[img]
```

How can I do that with sed? I tried this one but it doesn't do anything:

```
sed -i 's/^[img:.*]/[img]/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Escape those square brackets

Square brackets are [metacharacters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter): they have a [special meaning in POSIX regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). If you mean `[` and `]` *literally*, you need to escape those characters in your regexp:

```sh
$ sed -i .bak 's/\[img:.*\]/\[img\]/g' file.txt
```

### Use `[^]]*` instead of `.*`

Because `*` is greedy, `.*` will capture more than what you want; see [Jidder's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696805/replace-string-between-square-brackets-with-sed#comment43812163_27696877). To fix this, use `[^]]*`, which captures a sequence of characters up to (but excluding) the first `]` encountered.

```sh
$ sed -i .bak 's/\[img:.[^]]\]/\[img\]/g' file.txt
```

### Are you using an incorrect `sed -i` syntax?

(Thanks to j.a. for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696805/replace-string-between-square-brackets-with-sed/27696877?noredirect=1#comment43809175_27696877).)

Depending on the flavour of `sed` that you're using, you may be allowed to use `sed -i` without specifying any `<extension>` argument, as in

```sh
$ sed -i 's/foo/bar/' file.txt
```

However, in other versions of `sed`, such as the one that ships with Mac OS X, `sed -i`  expects a *mandatory* `<extension>` argument, as in

```sh
$ sed -i .bak 's/foo/bar/' file.txt
```

If you omit that extension argument (`.bak`, here), you'll get a syntax error. You should check out your `sed`'s man page to figure out whether that argument is optional or mandatory.

### Match a specific number of characters

> [Is there a way to tell `sed` that there are always 8 random characters after the colon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696805/replace-string-between-square-brackets-with-sed/27696877#comment43808150_27696877)

Yes, there is. If the number of characters between the colon and the closing square bracket is always the same (8, here), you can make your command more specific:

```sh
$ sed -i .bak 's/\[img:[^]]\{8\}\]/\[img\]/g' file.txt
```

### Example

```sh
# create some content in file.txt
$ printf "[img:3gso40ßf]\nfoo [img:4t5457th]\n" > file.txt

# inspect the file
$ cat file.txt
[img:3gso40ßf]
foo [img:4t5457th]

# carry out the substitutions
$ sed -i .bak 's/\[img:[^]]\{8\}\]/\[img\]/g' file.txt

# inspect the file again and make sure everything went smoothly
$ cat file.txt
[img]
foo [img]

# if you're happy, delete the backup that sed created
$ rm file.txt.bak
```

Comment: Okay, that deletes a lot of stuff. I'm actually running this over an SQL backup. Probably a bad idea, but mysql replace can't handle wildcards. It deletes too much from the database, but it's a start. Is there a way to tell sed that there are always 8 random characters after the colon?

Comment: Notice that [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) `-i` option's syntax is as follows: `-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]`. The brackets mean the suffix is optional.

Comment: @j.a. Not in my version of `sed` (I'm on Mac OS X, which is based on BSD); the suffix argument is mandatory if you use the `-i` flag; if you don't want to keep a backup, you need to pass an empty string.

Comment: You're right @Jubobs, I've seen it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html). Anyway, the OP didn't say he's using Mac OS X, so I think it would be a good idea to clarify. ...Or just leave these comments.

Comment: @j.a. Yes, I can see how confusion could arise. I'll edit the answer accordingly. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The problem with wildcards may be because `.*` is greedy and will match the longest case. Using `[^]]*` as in `'s/\[img:[^]]*\]/\[img\]/g'` may solve the problem and works with all seds(AFAIK).

Comment: Thank you, guys! I was able to fix all broken BBCodes with your syntax and migrate a decade-old Snitz Forum to Kunena perfectly! :) May i-war2.com/forum live for another 15 years. And actually, I'm running Debian, so it wasn't a problem.