# sed with option -i and flag /d set

Tags: shell, sed, gnu

What does this sed command in a shell script do?

```
sed -i /'abc'/d  "/etc/rc.d/rc.local"
```

More precisely, what does '-i' do here? And why there is a 'd' flag set at the pattern's end?

Comment: `man sed`, press `/` for search, and type `-i` :-) ... The `d` command will delete lines that match the pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From sed manual, `i` option means in-place edit

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

   edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

`d` means delete action

```
d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
```

In you example, this two combination will delete any line contain `abc` in the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` without backup.

Comment: for making this simple +1

Comment: For information, in some versions of `sed` (like the BSD one that ships with Mac OS X), the `SUFFIX` argument is mandatory; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27696877/2541573).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

1. check it out at [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sed+-i+%2F%27abc%27%2Fd++%22%2Fetc%2Frc.d%2Frc.local%22)
2. use man page